# MySQL Order with decimals

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've got a problem with mysql ordering.
My query:

`SELECT * FROM versions ORDER BY version DESC`

It lists some of the versions like this:

```
25.0.1364.86
25.0.1364.124
23.0.1271.100
```

however .124 is higher than .86.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Store it as 4 integer columns - `major`, `minor`, `patch` and `build`

Comment: Your problem is that they're not decimals, they're strings. As such they're being compared as strings.

Comment: @MarkParnell And what's the resolution?

Comment: @zerkms The problem's that the theme's not the same at the versions.

Comment: @Skylineman as @zerkms said store it as separate columns, or reformat it e.g. as @Chris suggested. Or if possible you could zero-pad the values, e.g. `25.0.1364.086` - whether that will work will depend on your versioning system.

Answer (score 3):

A small improvement to the query posted from @peterm (with thanks!)

```
SELECT *
FROM `versions`
ORDER BY 1*SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 1) asc, 
     1*SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', -3),'.', 1) asc, 
     1*SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', -2),'.', 1) asc, 
     1*SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', -1) asc,
     version asc # this will sort non-numeric strings
```

I tested with more complicated values, letters, numbers, dashes and points, as versions can be written in any format.

```
| version |
-----------
| a-b     |
| a-c     |
| ab      |
| b       |
| c       |
| c.a     |
| c.a.b   |
| c.b     |
| c.b.a   |
| c.b.b   |
| ca      |
| 1.2     |
| 1.2.1   |
| 2.1.1   |
| 2.1.2   |
| 3       |
| 10      |
| 123     |
```

Answer (score 2):

If the format of `version` column is fixed then you can split the version into parts and `ORDER BY` them.

```
SELECT *
FROM versions
ORDER BY 1*SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', 1) DESC, 
         1*SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', -3),'.', 1) DESC, 
         1*SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', -2),'.', 1) DESC, 
         1*SUBSTRING_INDEX(version, '.', -1) DESC
```

Output:

```
|       VERSION |
-----------------
| 25.0.1364.124 |
| 25.0.1364.86  |
| 23.0.1271.100 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8a2c/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but there is a much easier answer to this using the INET_ATON() function.

```
SELECT * FROM versions ORDER BY INET_ATON(version)
```

will output

```
23.0.1271.100
25.0.1364.86
25.0.1364.124
```

Read more about INET_ATON() here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how the table `versions` is defined it is difficult to answer for sure, but that looks like it is being searched as text, in which case 86 is greater than 124 (think of dictionary ordering).
One simple solution might be to store the data in two formats in your table - keep the string you seem to have, and have a decimal equivalent, for example 25.0.1364.86 as a string and 2501364.86 as a decimal. This would ensure your ordering worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach (hope you don't mind I [blogged about it](http://www.jadito.us/2013/03/12/sorting-software-versions/)):

```
SELECT v.version 
FROM   (SELECT version, 
               Cast(Substring_index(version, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)  major, 
               Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(version, '.' 
                   , 2 ), '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)                    minor, 
               Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(version, '.' 
                   , -2 ), '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)                    patch, 
               Cast(Substring_index(version, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) build 
        FROM   versions) v 
ORDER  BY v.major, 
          v.minor, 
          v.patch, 
          v.build
```

**Result**

```
|       VERSION |
-----------------
| 23.0.1271.100 |
|  25.0.1364.86 |
| 25.0.1364.124 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55668/3)

Comment: The only problem's that we don't know how long is the version number :/